# Laravel 9 No envía correo

Tags: laravel, php8

Hola tengo un problema con laravel 9 y el envió de correo desde mi hosting, el cual es compartido.

El problema es el siguiente, hago una instalación limpia de laravel 9 con la versión de PHP 8.1 y hago todos los pasos para usar la verificación de email de los usuarios. En este momento no e escrito ningún código dentro de mi aplicación, solo e usado composer y el comando artisan para generar el proyecto.

Inicio el servidor y todo funciona bien en cuanto a al registro de los usuarios y demás pantallas de bienvenida de laravel 9; pero el correo jamás llega al destinatario con los datos de mi servidor.

Si uso los datos de mailtrap o mailgun, los correos llegan a su destinatario en el caso de mailgun y con mailtrap llegan al tablero de trabajo.

Esto indicaría que mi correo del hosting es el problema, pero es el mismo correo que uso para mis aplicaciones que desarrollo en C# y también tengo una aplicación en el mismo servidor en un subdominio que usa laravel 8 y PHP 8.1 y también mandan correo y llegan a sus destinatario.

Quien con una idea o un error similar, ya que no se que hacer.

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindar.

Comment: ¿De que panel de control de hosting estamos hablando?  cpanel? plesk? otro?

Comment: Hola. Es un cPanel de hostgator